# A function to convert words to numbers

Tags: r, stringr

I came across this function that converts numbers written in words into its numeric representation (e.g., five to 5). The function looks like this:

```
library(english)

words_to_numbers <- function(s) {
  s <- stringr::str_to_lower(s)
  for (i in 0:11)
    s <- stringr::str_replace_all(s, words(i), as.character(i))
  s
}
```

Can you explain how the function works? I am confused how `as.character()` is playing a role here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function works like this (note you also need the `stringr` package).

1. First, it takes the word you input (i.e. `"five"` if you used `words_to_numbers("five")`)
2. Then, `str_to_lower()` takes that and normalizes it to all lower case (i.e., avoiding issues if you typed `"Five"` or `"FIVE"` instead of `"five"`).
3. It then iterates over a loop (for some reason ending at 11), so `i` will take the value of `1`, then `2`, then `3`, all the way to `11`.
4. Within the loop, `str_replace_all()` takes your string (i.e., `"five"`) and looks for a matching pattern. Here, the pattern is `words(i)` (i.e. `words(5)` when `i == 5` yields the pattern `"five"` - in the `english` package, the `words()` function provides a vector of words that represent the position in the vector. For instance, if you type `english::words(1000)` it will return `"one thousand"`. Once it finds the pattern, it then replaces it with `as.character(i)`. The `as.character()` function converts the number `i` value to a character since `str_replace_all()` requires a character replacement. If you needed the return value to be numeric, you could use `as.numeric(words_to_numbers("five"))`

For some reason, the function stops at 11, meaning if you type `words_to_numbers("twelve")` it won't work (returns "twelve"). So you will need to adjust that number if you want to use the function for values > 11.

Hope this helps and good luck learning R!

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation. I really appreciate your time and effort!! Yeah, it now makes sense.